# Getting Errorlevel =1 while i was running Jmeter using non graphical usermode

Tags: jmeter

C:\Users\Tammina User\OneDrive\Desktop\Mansoor\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\bin>jmeter -n -t \Users\Tammina User\OneDrive\Desktop\Mansoor\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\backups\l1-000001.jmx -l \Users\Tammina User\OneDrive\Desktop\Mansoor\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\backups\Load.csv
WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
WARN StatusConsoleListener The use of package scanning to locate plugins is deprecated and will be removed in a future release
An error occurred: Unknown arg: User\OneDrive\Desktop\Mansoor\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\backups\l1-000001.jmx
errorlevel=1
Press any key to continue . . .

I have recheck it by creating a new folder naming as file for the csv and added the load.csv file over there

Answer (score 0):

If the path to your test script and/or results file contains special characters you need to surround it with quotation marks (or [escape them in another way](https://www.howtogeek.com/694949/how-to-escape-spaces-in-file-paths-on-the-windows-command-line/) if you prefer)

Something like:

```
jmeter -n -t \Users\"Tammina User"\OneDrive\Desktop\Mansoor\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\backups\l1-000001.jmx -l \Users\"Tammina User"\OneDrive\Desktop\Mansoor\Jmeter\apache-jmeter-5.6.2\backups\Load.csv
```

More information:

- [CLI Mode (Command Line mode was called NON GUI mode)](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
- [JMeter Non-GUI Mode: Useful Tips](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-non-gui-mode)